# How to implement continuous parallax like this?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been playing around with HTML, CSS, and jQuery, and I can't figure out how to implement the parallax functionality on this website: http://quinntonharris.strikingly.com/

Each slide manages to seamlessly "cover up" the previous slide while being able to be covered up by the following slide, while all managing to relatively move at the same speed.

I've tried doing this in CSS alone by just creating different layers, but then the slides don't move at the same speed. I've also looked at examples like on this: https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/demo3/ but they don't simulate the same effect.

What's the essential concept in emulating this effect using vanilla CSS or with jQuery/some other JS library?

Comment: Looks to me like a series of `overflow: hidden` divs form the scroll content, while their children are animated in the inverse direction of the scrolling.

Comment: The graphics are background images. The parallax is achieved by using javascript to change the background offsets as the page is scrolled.

Answer (score 1):

We'll scroll a series of `overflow: hidden` divs (call these "parallaxParents"). Scrolls will cause the children ("parallaxChildren") of these "parallaxParents" to animate in the inverse direction of the scroll.

This technique looks especially great when parallaxParents take up the full size of their scrolling viewport.

```js
let initialChildMarginTop = -125; // parallaxChild's margin-top

let scroller = document.getElementsByClassName('scroller')[0];
let doParallax = () => {
  
  // An Array of all parallaxParents
  let pars = Array.from(scroller.getElementsByClassName('parallaxParent'));
  
  // The height of a parallaxParent
  let parHeight = pars[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
  pars.forEach((par, ind) => {
    
    // Get the parallaxChild...
    let child = par.getElementsByClassName('parallaxChild')[0];
    
    // Represents how close `par` is to the center of the scroller viewport
    // 0 means centered; < 0 is above, > 0 is below
    let focusedAmt = (ind * parHeight) - scroller.scrollTop;
    
    // Shift each child by a fraction of `focusedAmt`
    // Children exactly in the middle of the viewport will be unchanged
    child.style.marginTop = `${initialChildMarginTop - Math.round(focusedAmt * 0.5)}px`;
    
  });
  
};

// May need to add the event listener in more places
scroller.addEventListener('scroll', doParallax);
window.addEventListener('resize', doParallax);

// Make sure everything is initially translated correctly
doParallax();
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

.scroller {
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-size: 0;
}
.parallaxParent {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
.parallaxParent:nth-child(2n) { background-color: rgba(100, 100, 0, 0.2); }
.parallaxParent:nth-child(2n + 1) { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 100, 0.2); }
.parallaxChild {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px; height: 250px;
  left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-left: -125px; margin-top: -125px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: rgba(0, 150, 100, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
  <div class="parallaxParent">
    <div class="parallaxChild"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parallaxParent">
    <div class="parallaxChild"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parallaxParent">
    <div class="parallaxChild"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parallaxParent">
    <div class="parallaxChild"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parallaxParent">
    <div class="parallaxChild"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parallaxParent">
    <div class="parallaxChild"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parallaxParent">
    <div class="parallaxChild"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parallaxParent">
    <div class="parallaxChild"></div>
  </div>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54775562/how-to-implement-continuous-parallax-like-this#
  <div class="parallaxParent">
    <div class="parallaxChild"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this may be a way to accomplish the effect, this isn't how it's done on the example page.

Comment: I think my implementation is 1-to-1, conceptually, with that page. Maybe it uses background-images, while I use child elements. The import concept is translating child content in the inverse direction of the scroll.

Comment: @GershomMaes Gershom Maes' implementation worked well for the instance I was trying to use it for! Thank you! I'm wondering though, how I can implement two more features. 1) how could I add text divs to overlay the images? That is, I'm trying to add "sticky" text that is overlayed on top of some of the pictures. and 2) I have a flex container that I'm trying to implement as well. Is the flex container compatible with this solution?

Comment: Here's an example of what I'm talking about: `<div class="parallaxParent"><div class="parallaxChild"><div class="name"> ⏤ SAMPLE TEXT ⏤ </div><--- Text div that doesn't appear ---></div></div>` Perhaps some explanation of your code would help?

Comment: The third thing is, how can I manipulate the script code so that I can change the height of certain parallaxParents while preserving the effect? Currently, increasing the height causes the following background to be pushed off the page and fill with white space.

Comment: 1 - Is the text `div` meant to go in the parent or the child? (Is it meant to scroll normally, or with the parallax effect applied?) You should be able to insert it into the html normally; for parent: `<div class="parallaxParent"><p>text text text</p><div class="parallaxChild"></div></div>`. For child: `<div class="parallaxChild"><p>text text text</p></div>`

Comment: 2 - There shouldn't be any problem using a flex container as a parallaxChild

Comment: 3 - If not all parallaxParents have the same height, you can't determine overall vertical offset by multiplying a constant by the index of the current parent. Instead you need to keep a running sum of heights of first-n parallaxParents. (e.g. something like `sumHeight += currentPar.getBoundingClientRect().height; let focusedAmt = sumHeight - scroller.scrollTop`). If you need more help in addition to this answer, you may want to ask another question! :)